# Image/photo frames

Tags: delphi, components

Is there any good component for Delphi to create a frame like the messenger frame around a photo?

Comment: @Wayne: No additional details are required, as far as I can see.

Comment: I am 100 % sure that there is a StackOverflow question about how to draw such a frame using Windows API. The OP then found out that this bitmap is stored as a resource bitmap in explorer.exe, IIRC. But - as usual - I cannot possibly find this question.

Comment: What is "the messenger frame"?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: He is referring to the frame surrounding the user picture in Microsoft Windows Live Messenger (msnmsgr.exe). Here is an example of this frame, surrounding my personal picture as used in association with my Windows Live ID account: http://privat.rejbrand.se/msnmsgrframe.png In this image, the frame is green, indicating that my status is "Online". Notice that this (or at least a very similar) frame is used in Windows itself, in the logon screen in Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the photo frame you want to see?

Comment: @Andreas, I catch now, thanks.  @Jlouro: for the messenger case, it is simple in the way the photo is always the same size, is that your case?

Comment: Yes. the Photo will always be the same size.

Comment: yes, ImageEN components has such option

Answer (score 3):

This frame is basically just a bitmap. There seems not to be any function in the Windows API to draw this. Instead, a previous questioner here at SO found that this (or at least a very similar) bitmap is stored as a resource bitmap in `explorer.exe`, if I recall correctly.

Hence, to write a Delphi component displaying a bitmap inside such a frame would be trivial -- one just have to copy this bitmap. However, I feel this would be wrong (copyvio or at least bad manners). But of course you can draw your own version of a frame /using The GIMP or Photoshop/, and include it as a bitmap.

Also notice that it is very easy to apply bitmap effects, such as hue shifts, to a bitmap during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at our MicroPic very small tool.
http://bouchez.info/micropic.html

You've got the source code on the page.
It could be interesting for you, as start for drawing a custom frame to any picture.
I wrote this years ago, just to help my girl friend with her web site, without using photoshop before inserting pictures...